# Select2 Customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using JQuery select2 in the below code

```
<div style="height:150px; overflow:hidden" id="cover">
    <select name="school id="school" class="select" style="width:220px;min-width:47px;">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

the select2 dropdown goes behind div with id "cover" and hence hiding dropdown menu partially.

i want to customize select2 in a way it display dropdown above the div with id "cover".

please help.

Comment: Please share your snippet

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the select line.

```
<select name="school" id="school" class="select" style="width:220px;min-width:47px;">
```

Comment: still same @ArcaneCraeda